# Asp.net MVC3, C#, Figure out Single or Multiple Json paramter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm passing to single JSON type parameter and multiple JSON type parameters to Asp.Net.

and in Asp.Net, I need to figure out the parameter is single data or multiple data to update DB (EF, Repository pattern).

[Single]

[image]

[Multiple]

[image]

Firstly, I tried like this,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ItemUpdate(WEBORDERLN ln ,IList<WEBORDERLN> lns)
{
```

**but it comes to ln always. it never go to lns :(**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ItemUpdate(WEBORDERLN ln)
{
// it works for only single update
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ItemUpdate(IList<WEBORDERLN> lns)
{
// it works for only multiple update
```

How I figure out, the JSON type parameter is single or multiple?

anybody know, please advice me.

Thank you!

[EDIT]

[image]

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ItemUpdate(WEBORDERLNS lns)
{
    try
    {
    EFWebOrderLnRepository webOrderLn = new EFWebOrderLnRepository();

    log.Debug("Count : "+lns.lns.Count.ToString()); // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    
    log.Debug(lns.lns.Count());  //null, error : Value cannot be null
    log.Debug(lns.lns.Count().ToString());  //null, error : Value cannot be null

    foreach (WEBORDERLN ln in lns.lns)
    {
        webOrderLn.updateWebOrderLn(ln); // Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    }
    .
    .
    .


public class WEBORDERLNS
{
    public IList<WEBORDERLN> lns { get; set; }
}
```

[EDIT]

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  875
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  user=38C6C07684B04645821CA5273EAB5B34340CE8CCA13A7D67DC748819B02C6963E4AD2A322068FC3090D3FE03EC81E663A5DED6FF2534E2595B40CF57EFF9BB544FFAC95CD79020E8A94019A3DC53B769EFC4049B6B9627E98AD9DBC1431BB5D99A47625B3353FA697A1CC005855C0248E95F61F7BD4A5362D75E5D01B395FB14E078524B8D0C7219AF959F9AED188AB30A16187DE166D5BD008B0013A65D470C52C9408C47FD42672B8FBABDB3524F77
Host    localhost:49995
Referer http://localhost:49995/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

[EDIT]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would actually be far better off creating a Model class which represents an order set, with a collection of WEBORDERLN exposed as a property.

```
public class OrderSet 
{
   public List<WEBORDERLN> OrderLines { get; set; }

}
```

On your controller method, change the incoming parameter to:-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ItemUpdate(OrderSet orders)
{
// it works for only multiple update
```

At that point, when receiving the model, you can just call the count mechanism on your `OrderLines` property.

```
// How many orders?
var orderCount = orders.OrderLines.Count;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still I couldn't solve the problem. I edited my question, could you review my question again please?

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution?

Comment: I believe so, I write the code in edited question too. could you review the code please? I don;t know what I am doing wrong.. thank you!

Comment: @Expertwannabe you pass these parameters with ajax ? If yes, can you show your code ?

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus Yes, I use Ajax and Extjs. so when I edit Extjs grid cell, Extjs send the data by Ajax to sink with DB. so actually I can not see the code generated. but I will add the header information into my question. thank you very much!

Comment: @Expertwannabe as you are in a post action : you could put a `FormCollection fc` as parameter of your action, and show us what's in this fc variable.

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus public ActionResult ItemUpdate(FormCollection fc){} then How can I see what's in fc varialble? ^^;

Comment: @Expertwannabe just debug, put a breakpoint inside Action, look what's in fc in a Watch window (Debug - windows -watch - watch1) where you write "fc".

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus I added the screen shot at end of question, could you take a look? I think it looks same passing single or multiple data.